# How to map dictionary outputs into tuple?

Tags: python

I have a generator like this:

```
class Generator():
    def __init__(self, features, labels):
        self.features = features
        self.labels = labels

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(len(self.features)):
            yield self.features[i], self.labels[i]
```

then we can get a callable generator function by `generator_fun = lambda: map(tuple, generator)`. But when I have another generator with dictionary outputs like this:

```
class DictGenerator():
    def __init__(self, features, labels):
        self.features = features
        self.labels = labels

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(len(self.features)):
            yield {"images": self.features[i], "labels": self.labels[i]}
```

How to get the callable func for the `DictGenerator`? From the callable function, I want to get the values of the dictionary, i.e., the same tuple outputs as that of Generator.

Comment: An instance of your first class is iterable, so you don't need to use `map()` to get tuples from it because that's what it yields. Regardless, if that works, why do you want complicate things with the second generator class?

Comment: @martineau thanks a lot for your kind comment. Sorry for unclear description. In fact, I need a `callable` generator function. The `iterable` seems not be a `callable` function. I've updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> dict_generator = DictGenerator(...)
>>> map(lambda x: tuple(x.values()), dict_generator)
```